# Complex Pointers and structures relation

Tags: c, pointers

Here is piece of code that I am struggling with. It is basically provided within an existing code. 
Can somebody please explain it:

```
typedef struct a* (*b)(struct c* d);
```

Comment: Simply the variable `b` holds the address of a function that returns a pointer to an `a` type structure, and takes as parameter a pointer to a `c` type structure. **`b` is a function pointer**.

Answer (score 3):

There is this famous left-right evaluation: start at the identifier, go to left until the first parenthesis, then go to right, etc.

This gives us here:

start at `b`: `b` is a …
go left, find the pointer: … pointer to…
go right, find the function definition: … a function taking `struct c* d` …
go left, find the remainder of the function definition: … returning `struct a*`.

So `b` is a pointer to a function taking `struct c* d` and returning `struct a*`.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code :

- define a new type of function: `typedef`
- named "`b`": `(*b)`
- returning a pointer on a `a` structure: `struct a*` (*b)
- taking a pointer on a `c` structure as parameter: `(struct c* d)`

The parameter is named `d`, but this information can be removed from declaration I think.

Answer (score 1):

It `typedef`'s a function pointer type (b).

A function such as ....

```
struct a *  MyFunction( struct c* d );
```

Has the same type as the typedef.

e.g.

```
  b myPointer = MyFunction;

  struct c d;
  myPointer( &d );
```

Comment: *Decays to* the same type as the typedef. Not that it changes much.

Answer (score 1):

This `typedef` defines an alias for a function type that accepts a `struct c*` and returns a `struct a*`, the alias is named `b`. formerly:

```
typedef struct a* (*b)(struct c* d);
           ^ 
           return type, pointer to struct a
                    ^
                    name of the function type alias
                        ^
                        arguments to the function, a pointer to a struct c
```

Answer (score 1):

It becomes clearer if you don't hide a pointer behind a `typedef`:

```
typedef struct a* b (struct c* d);
```

where `struct a* b (struct c* d);` is a plain old function declaration. With the typedef, `b` doesn't become the name of the function, but the name of the type. In your case with `(*b)`, the `b` becomes the name of a function pointer type.

If we use the version of `typedef` posted above and need a function pointer of that type, we would declare it as `b* ptr;`. Whereas in your code, you would write `b ptr;` and not realize that the variable is actually a pointer.

Generally, hiding pointers behind a `typedef` is bad practice, as we get more readable code if we don't.